# How to compare table schema on a database with an sql script file in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Let say I have a table name `Anonymous` on a database and I have a file name `Anonymous.sql` on my harddrive. I want to know if the table's schema is as same as or difference from the schema define in `Anonymous.sql`. The sql file has a CREATE schema.

My questions are:

1. How to compare a table's schema with a schema in an sql file?
2. If they have any difference, how can I alter the table on the database?

Answer (score 0):

If your table schema is in sql file, you can you beyond comparer software to compare those files.

And if you have any changes, change with that software and rerun the table schema in sql server with the prefix "alter table name"

for software download

http://beyond-compare.en.softonic.com/